# I am not getting any event in webhook url using stripe

Tags: java, grails, stripe-payments

I have implemented a webhook url in the stripe account. I am getting an notification in the webhook url but not getting any event. It means I am getting an empty notification in the webhook url.

Fig shows Stripe account test result of webhook url

[image]

and webhook url code

```
 def stripeEventHandler(){
    println("=========Stripe Request===============")
    println("${params}")
    println("========================")
     render view:'index'

}
```

And server logs

```
2014-01-10T12:58:17.799473+00:00 app[web.1]: =========Stripe Request===============
2014-01-10T12:58:17.799749+00:00 app[web.1]: [action:stripeEventHandler, controller:home]
2014-01-10T12:58:17.799941+00:00 app[web.1]: ========================
```

Please Help

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I Have fixed this issue. The simple fix is

```
request.JSON
```

Comment: why you down voted this answer. Please give me some explanation.